# Freemarker: How to put XML into data-model?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

Followed Freemarker [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_expose_put.html)

**Controller**

```
public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("users", userList);
        mav.addObject("user", "Big Joe");
        mav.addObject("title", "Testing initial page, using FreeMarker!");
        try {
            mav.addObject("doc", freemarker.ext.dom.NodeModel.parse (new File("C:\\Users\\Himanshuy\\Desktop\\2.xml")));

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

**Error**

```
FreeMarker template error: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel): ==> header [in template "index.ftl" at line 13, column 3
```

**FTL**

```
<#assign header=doc.title >
${header}
```

**XML**

```
<book>
  <title>Test Book</title>
  <chapter>
    <title>Ch1</title>
    <para>p1.1</para>
    <para>p1.2</para>
    <para>p1.3</para>
  </chapter>
  <chapter>
    <title>Ch2</title>
    <para>p2.1</para>
    <para>p2.2</para>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be `doc.book.title` (and you don't need that `#assign` of course), since `doc` is the XML document, which is not the same as the topmost element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you shouldn't use ${header} in your ftl, look at this page for more examples on how to utilize the xml file: 
http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html